# std::unique_ptr declared on base class

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

Sorry about the title, I couldn't come with a better one.

Suppose that I have a class with *special* delete semantics, which needs to call a function instead of been deleted by `delete`, let's call it `releaseable_object`:

```
struct releaseable_object
{
    releaseable_object() : dummy_ptr(new int) {}
    void Release()
    {
        std::cout << "Releasing releaseable object\n";
        delete dummy_ptr;
    }
    int *const dummy_ptr;
};
```

And this `releaseable_object` is the base class of a bunch of other objects, each of them constructed by a factory which only returns pointers.

I'm trying to wrap each class into a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter which call the `releaseable_object::Release()` function, so I've created a helper struct to handle some of the generic stuff:

```
// std::is_base_of<releaseable_object, T>::value must be true
template <typename T> struct Managed
{
    using type = T;
    static void deleter(type *object)
    {
        std::cout << "Release!\n";
        object->Release();
    };
    using pointer = std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)>;
};
```

And then, a bunch of derived classes which does all the specific initializations and calls to te factory:

```
struct ManagedA : Managed<A>
{
    using base = Managed<A>;
    using base::pointer;
    using base::deleter;
    ManagedA(/* lots of parameters */) :
        m_pointer(nullptr, deleter)
    {
        // do A specific stuff...
        A *a = factory::CreateA(/* lots of parameters */);
        // more A specific stuff...

        // wrap the pointer:
        m_pointer.reset(a);
    }
    pointer m_pointer;
};
```

If I try to compile the code above, it complains about the `unique_ptr` ([demo here](http://ideone.com/9VJSlT)), I don't know what I'm doing wrong there, the error is about the instantiation of a tuple (the complete error log is in the ideone demo):

```
tuple: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Head_base<1u, void(A*), false>’:
tuple:229:12:   recursively required from ‘struct std::_Tuple_impl<1u, void(A*)>’
tuple:229:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Tuple_impl<0u, A*, void(A*)>’
tuple:521:11:   required from ‘class std::tuple<A*, void(A*)>’
bits/unique_ptr.h:127:57:   required from ‘class std::unique_ptr<A, void(A*)>’
```

If I get rid of the `m_pointer` member then the compilation succeeds. I'm pretty lost with this, I'll be grateful of any hints about how to fix the compilation error.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Isn't easier to overload `delete`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `decltype(deleter)` is a function type instead of a pointer-to-function type. Changing the `pointer` declaration to

```
using pointer = std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)*>; // or spell out void(*)(T*)
```

will fix it.

Be aware that a function object type is usually preferable to a function pointer type for a unique pointer deleter, since the function pointer must be stored in the object itself. i.e.,

```
sizeof(std::unique_ptr<foo*,void(*)(foo*)>) == sizeof(foo*) + sizeof(void(*)(foo*))
```

but most implementations will take advantage of the Empty Base Optimization if you use an empty deleter type:

```
struct deleter_type {
  void operator () (foo*) {
    // ...
  }
};
sizeof(std::unique_ptr<foo*,deleter_type>) == sizeof(foo*)
```

[Here's how your sample code would be written using a deleter type.](http://ideone.com/wnmk9p).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I added a little more info about why using a deleter type is usually preferred to a deleter function.

Comment: very useful! but I've already +1'ed you, I cannot add more points to your score! ;)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I don't care much about the Internet points - I care about giving useful advice ;)

Comment: if that's the case, you achieved your goal pretty well, thank you :)